# How is Glycophorin A and straphylococcal related to Escherichia coli and what does readily purified mean in this context?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, enzymes, red-blood-cell, protein-interaction

I am reviewing the paper "Glycophorin A Dimerization Is Driven by Specific Interactions between Transmembrane Alpha-Helices."  There is a statement in the abstract which I don't understand:

"The transmembrane alpha-helical domain of interest is fused to the C-terminus of staphylococcal nuclease.  The resulting chimera can be expressed at high levels in Escherichia coli and is readily purified."

As I understand it, this describes that an alpha-helix within Glycophorin A is fused to straphylococcal nuclease?  Then, how does Escherichia coli come into the discussion and what is meant by being readily purified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, they engineered a vector which, when transfected to E. coli, produces transcripts of -and thus proteins to- a fusion gene which produces these transmembrane α helices conjugated to the staphylococcal nuclease. In other words, the E. coli are just factories for producing proteins:

> *Expression, Extraction, and Purification of SN/GpA* - For high
>   levels of SN/GpA production, pT7SN/GpA was transformed into E.
>   coli MGT7 (kindly provided by D. LeMaster), containing the plasmid
>   pLYS-S.

And the reasoning therein was proposed in the discussion,

> We report here the use of a chimeric protein to show that
>   the presence of just the transmembrane domain of GpA, fused
>   to a normally monomeric soluble protein, is sufficient to
>   mediate the dimerization of this artificial membrane protein
>   -in SDS

What they mean by readily purified is that the protein can be extracted relatively easily, and in the experimental method they explain some commonplace methods of purification:

> One-step purification of milligram quantities of SN/GpA from the
>   extract could be achieved by reversed-phase HPLC utilizing an acetonitrile/isopropyl
>   alcohol/water gradient on a semipreparative Vydac
>   C4 column. Alternatively, purification of larger quantities was
>   achieved using two rounds of cation-exchange chromatography...
>
> ...The chimera SN/GpA131, but not truncated forms, could alterNaCl,
>   50 mM Tris-HC1, 5 mM EDTA, 1 mM PMSF, 0.025% NaNa,
>   natively be extracted by sonication of the pellet after cell lysis in 1 M
>   pH 7.9, containing no detergent. This extraction was of similar
>   efficiency to that with Lubrol, and was utilized in the preparation of
>   material for generation of transmembrane peptide by trypsin treatment.